# TypeORM MongoDB aggregate

Tags: mongodb, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

In my NestJS project I am trying to use aggregate but I cannot get it to work, and the documentation is very scarce.

My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity()
export class MyItem {
    
   @Column()
   risktype?: string;
   ...
}
```

This is the service:

```
getTopNRiskNames$(n: number) {
    return this.myitemRepository.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: { risktype: "$risktype" },
                $count: { $sum: 1 }
             }
        }
     ])        
}
```

and this is the controller:

```
@Get('getTopNRiskNames/:n')
async getTopNRiskNames(@Param('n') n: number) {
    return  this.myItemService.getTopNRiskNames$(n);
}
```

But when I call it with Postman I just get back this:

```
{
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 0
}
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: May be syntax wrong. Use `count` instead of `$count`

Comment: @DoanThai thanks but that's not it. Other simple queries such as this.myitemRepository.find({ linkeditems: { $in: linkedids } }) work, so I guess the $ operators work